# Instantiating an object in a namespace with a constructor whose defined in the same namespace. C++

Tags: c++, header, namespaces, multiple-definition-error

While attempting to make a function object wrapper class for raw functions, I'm encountering a multiple definition error by trying to define in a namespace in a header file and declare it in the source. This works fine but when I try to instantiate a function object based on the raw function in the namespace, I get the error.

space.h

```
#ifndef SPACE_H
#define SPACE_H
namespace fobj{

class function_object
{
public:
    function_object(double (*f)(double)) { raw_function = f; }
    double operator()(double x) {return raw_function(x); }
private:
    double (*raw_function)(double);
};

}

namespace fraw {

double raw(double x);

/** below is the trouble maker. When removed, the error doesn't occur. But also,
    when the above is instead declared inline, the error doesn't occur either. **/

fobj:: function_object obj( raw ); 

}
#endif
```

space.cpp

```
#include "space.h"

double fraw:: raw(double x) { return x; }
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "space.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout<< fraw::raw(1.5)<<std::endl;
    std::cout<< fraw::obj(2.5)<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`fobj:: function_object obj( raw );` is a definition - including the header in multiple translation units breaks the one definition rule. Declare the variable as `extern` and define it in a single implementation file.